# ALIGN_JUSTIFIED for iText list item

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to set alignment to list items by writing this code -

```
ListItem alignJustifiedListItem =
    new ListItem(bundle.getString(PrintKeys.AckProcess), normalFont8);
alignJustifiedListItem.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
```

I see this doesn't make any change on alignment (defaulted as left aligned). Changing it to 
`alignJustifiedListItem.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);` is actually working but then the last line of the content also expands (as mentioned in doc, as well)

I dont understand when `ListItem` extends `Paragraph`, how `setAlignment()` behaviour can change. I don't see any overriding as well.

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
 <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
 <version>5.5.4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Got the issue. The problem comes when you have '\' character in list item content. Bruno, can you kindly suggest on resolve?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Stop thinking that iText is specifically targeted by users' *" trend where more and more people post questions saying that something doesn't work in iText"*. -- Live up to the fact that users with a problem do say so in relation to ***ALL*** software they use :-)  -- iText is important (to you and to a lot of its users), but it is not the center of the universe to be picked for blaming.

Comment: @naw: Why didn't you upvote Bruno's answer?!? -- The rules of this site are these: as someone asking a question, you should *upvote* any answers which helped you to solve the problem, and additionally *accept* this answer, which helped you *best* or *completely* to solve it. So ask yourself: *"Did Bruno's (several times update) answer help me?"*

Comment: One of the (few) illnesses on StackExchange is this: people who have no "domain knowhow" about PDF vote to close questions they do not understand themselves, or where they do not know the answer. Happened to questions I intended to answer too (topics were PDF, Ghostscript, PostScript, ImageMagick). I suppose this happens with other, more "popular" topics too...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: It also would help to upvote the question itself (you never do that, or?)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: IMHO, that's a stupid rule that you imposed upon yourself! -- BTW, I didn't intent to have any "bad" tone with my question -- I was honestly asking it. Because I had noticed in the past [as well as today] that you had provided very good and enlightening answers to questions which did not have a single upvote, and which I then proceeded to both upvote myself. That's what made me (wrongly, it seems) think you don't upvote questions... As for the question which you wanted re-opened: **mine** was the only upvote for it when I came across it after your hint.

Comment: I like the mechanism where good stuff is upvoted and bad stuff is downvoted. The rule is there to avoid that negativity gets the upper hand. As for the question that was closed: I am not going to upvote it, because IMHO it's not an intelligent question. It deserves an answer, not an upvote.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: After lot of head scratching, was able to resolve all issues. Char '\' was not the only issue. I added ListItems inside PDFCell and was not working even after setting required alignment to listitem. I added this piece of code to the PDF Table cell inviteQuestCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED); and it worked like charm. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ListAlignment](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ListAlignment) example.

In this example, I create a list with three list items of which I set the alignment to `ALIGN_JUSTIFIED`:

```
List list = new List(List.UNORDERED);
ListItem item = new ListItem(text);
item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
list.add(item);
text = "a b c align ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text = text + text;
}
item = new ListItem(text);
item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
list.add(item);
text = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious ";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    text = text + text;
}
item = new ListItem(text);
item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
list.add(item);
document.add(list);
```

If you look at the result, you can see that the alignment works as expected:

[image]

I deliberately introduced a very long word such as "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" to show you that all lines but the last are indeed justified.

**Update:**

In a comment, you claim that the alignment is wrong when you introduce the `\` character, and you want me to fix iText. However, there is nothing to fix.

I have adapted the original example like this:

```
text = "a b c align ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text = text + "\\" + text;
}
item = new ListItem(text);
item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
list.add(item);
text = "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious ";
text = text + text;
text = text + text;
text = text + "\n" + text;
item = new ListItem(text);
item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
list.add(item);
```

In the first case, I have introduce the `\` character. This didn't change anything to the behavior of the `ListItem`. In the second case, I introduce a newline character. The result was as expected: a newline character was introduced and the last line of every "paragraph" that was defined by the newline character was indeed not justified. That is what one would normally expect. I would introduce a bug if I would change this.

This is the screen shot of the result:

[image]

The introduction of the `'\'` character in the lines with `"a b c align "` doesn't have any effect on the alignment. The introduction of the newline half way the `"supercalifragilisticexpialidocious "` part breaks the list item in two parts. The final line of each part is not justified, which is the **desired behavior**.

If you do not want this desired behavior, you have to parse the content first and remove all newlines characters (carriage return and line feed).

**Update:**

In a new comment, you mention the `'\'` character as an escape character for the `'''` character (actually the `\'` character). I have adapted the original example once more:

```
text = "a b c\' align ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text = text + text;
}
item = new ListItem(text);
item.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
list.add(item);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The text is justified correctly. However, I can imagine that problems can occur if you handle `String`s with escape characters incorrectly. In this case, the `'\''` character was hardcoded. If you obtain the `String` from a database and you read that `String` incorrectly, then you can have strange results. Especially from my days as a PHP developer, I remember instances where a single quote ended up to be stored like this `'\\\''` in a database if you didn't watch out.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I never said that the last line is not justified but with using 'ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL', the last line is not getting justified. And if i use 'ALIGN_JUSTIFIED', the entire text is not getting justified. Even am not saying its an issue with IText, may be am missing something, at my end. But if i change the listitem to paragraph, everything works as excepted.

Comment: Got the issue. The problem comes when you have '\' character in list item content. Bruno, can you kindly suggest on resolve?

Comment: I do not understand what there is to resolve. I have updated my question: (1) to prove that the behavior doesn't change when you introduce a `'\'` character, and (2) that the behavior changes as expected when you introduce a newline. Maybe I've interpreted your question incorrectly, but if that's the case, **you should learn how to provide a SSCCE instead of saying "it doesn't work!"**

Comment: I have an apostrophe in my String (the Bank's), as char(') is not supported, i had to place the required unicode - \u2019 for ('). Now as my unicode contains Char(\), am facing this problem. If i remove this character, everything works as expected.

Comment: In that case, there's something wrong with the way you process `String`s. I'll update my answer to show you that it's not an iText but a general Java problem.